# Fragment Import problems messing with FragmentTransaction.replace

Tags: android, android-fragments

Interesting problem here. I have 2 identical `Fragments` and they both `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` but when I try to preform a `FragmentTransaction.replace()` on them the compiler accepts MyFrag2 but gives an error on MyFrag1.

I know whats causing it, but I don't know why. If I change the import in MyFrag1 from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `android.app.Fragment` the error goes away. And if I import `android.app.Fragment` on both classes the error flips and I get the error on MyFrag2. The fragment classes are the same in terms of how the fragments are setup. What gives?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class SettingsFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_fragmentactivity);

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if(savedInstanceState != null) return;

            MyFrag1 frag = new MyFrag1();

            android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction;
            transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();



//ERROR ON THIS LINE
//"replace (int, android.app.Fragment) to (int, MyFrag1)"
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag)


            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(long id) {
        MyFrag2 frag = new MyFrag2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong("id", id);
        frag.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


//NO ERROR!? The compiler happily accepts my offering.
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);


        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

---

MyFrag1

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MyFrag1 extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);

        ...//setup listadapter etc.

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.settings_devicelist);
    }

    ...

}
```

---

MyFrag2

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyFrag2 extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout, container, false);

    ...//setup listadapter etc.

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.settings_nodedmxdevice);
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [FragmentActivity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html):

> When using this class as opposed to new platform's built-in fragment and loader support, you must use the [getSupportFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) and [getSupportLoaderManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportLoaderManager()) methods respectively to access those features.

So replace your `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()` and ensure all of your imports (for example, `FragmentTransaction`), point to the support library versions.

Comment: that did it! thought it'd be something pretty simple